# URLSafe datastore key for Google Cloud Datastore Entity

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to get the "URL-safe key" for a Google Cloud Datastore entity. As per the documentation - https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6361641?hl=en - the Google Cloud Datastore client should have a function to do the same. However, I am not able to locate it. Can someone help with this? I am using the Python lib. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked this reference on [Google Cloud Datastore keys](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datastore/latest/keys) as well?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a key called `myKey`, following are your options

1. If you're using the Datastore library, you'll invoke the `to_legacy_urlsafe` method (see [source](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datastore/latest/keys#tolegacyurlsafelocationprefixnone)). This means you do `myKey.to_legacy_urlsafe()`

   To convert a urlsafe string back to key object, you call `from_legacy_urlsafe` method (see [source](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/datastore/latest/keys#classmethod-fromlegacyurlsafeurlsafe)). This means you do `google.cloud.datastore.key.Key.from_legacy_urlsafe(<urlsafe_key>)`
2. If you're using the `bundled ndb API`, you invoke the  `urlsafe` method on a key (see [source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/db175aa2e16a8417345c11ebe7e0d365e45d9f3b/src/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py#L587)). This means you do `myKey.urlsafe()`

   To convert a urlsafe string back to key object, you call `ndb.Key(urlsafe=<urlsafe_key>)` (see [source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-python-standard/blob/main/src/google/appengine/ext/ndb/key.py#L144))